# "use of unresolved identifier 'self'" when I don't use lazy modifier in Swift Playground

Tags: swift, swift-playground

I have defined the following enumeration

```
enum Languages :String {
case Spanish = "Spanish"
case English = "English"
case German = "German"
```

}

and I have the following class with a property and a func that uses that property as a block:

```
class Person {
     var language:Languages = Languages.Spanish

    var rosettaStoneCourse:Languages -> Void = {
        (lang:Languages) -> Void in
        self.language = lang
    }

    func learnLanguage(lang:Languages, course:(Languages) -> Void {
        course(lang)
    }
}
```

It might be easier for you to just copy and paste that all into your own Playground file to see my errors, but I'll list them here if you don't want to do that. I'm getting the following errors

in `self.language = lang` I'm getting a "use of unresolved identifier `self`

in the `learnLanguage` function it's suggesting to put a comma after the word `Void`

and at the closing curly brace of the `learnLanguage` it's saying `Expected '}'` in parameter.

The strangest thing of all, is if I add the lazy modifier to the `rosettaStoneCourse`, the first error I listed goes away!

Is there any sense to this, or is this just because `Playground` is in beta and we should expect strange things?